# puppet agent looks running but in foreman the last update is month ago

Tags: puppet, agent, foreman

i am using puppet 5.5. in station the agent looks running. but really the last report is month ago (usally it's running every 10 min)
when i am running the command 'puppet agent -t' i am getting this error:

```
puppet agent -t
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: sslv3 alert certificate unknown
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: sslv3 alert certificate unknown
Error: /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///pluginfacts: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: sslv3 alert certificate unknown
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/cache/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: sslv3 alert certificate unknown
Error: /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/cache/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///plugins: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: sslv3 alert certificate unknown
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: sslv3 alert certificate unknown
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: sslv3 alert certificate unknown
```

Comment: The agent is rejecting the master's SSL certificate.  You might get a bit more detail about that by adding `--debug` to the agent's command line: `puppet agent -t --debug`.  Meanwhile, make sure that it is talking to the master it should be talking to.  You should see the connection attempts in the master's logs, for example.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue on some of my systems.

Answer (score 2):

The clue to resolving this is in the paths puppet is searching through to find custom facts and libraries. The cause of this issue is a cached SSL certificate in the C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/cache directory. you can search for "*.pem" files using that path and if you find any that match your hostname, delete them. You'll then need to make sure you clean any old certs for the host from the puppet master server `puppet cert clean <hostname>` and then run the puppet agent on the host again to generate new certificates, using `puppet agent -tv`. Sign the new certs again on the master server `puppet cert sign <hostname>` and you should be good to go.